# Method not found: 'System.Object Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IAnnotatable.get_Item(System.String)'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm using C# and I want to `Add-Migration InitialVersion` but have an problem:

`Method not found: 'System.Object Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IAnnotatable.get_Item(System.String)'`

Nuget packages which I use:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.2.21154.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-preview.2.21154.2">
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.0-alpha.2" />
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrade `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` to latest [5th](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/5.0.4) version. You can do it via dotnet CLI using next command:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 5.0.4
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 5.0.4
```

[Indexer accepting `string`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.3/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/IAnnotatable.cs#L27) was removed from `IAnnotatable` in the [6th preview version](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v6.0.0-preview.2.21154.2/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/IAnnotatable.cs).

Comment: @TheRain clean `bin` and `obj` folders, rebuild, check that build output  directory contains  correct version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` packages.

Comment: But this can lead to a compatibility error, can't it?

Comment: @TheRain your original error was a compatibility error. `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2`  is depended on 5th version of EF Core but it seems that they allow higher versions to be used and 6th preview version has a breaking change (indexer was removed).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to update dotnet-ef to the same version as in your project

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0-preview.2.21154.2
```